# C++ class template constructor making decision based on type

Tags: c++11, templates, c++14, overloading, partial-specialization

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27943503/specialize-a-template-class-constructor/27943618#27943618) but it does not specifically answer my question. I have a simple class template that only takes one parameter. It does not store any member variables and has no methods other than a simple constructor. Based on the type passed in I need to branch my logic within the constructor. A simple version shell of the class would look like this as to what I'm trying to do. The class will take `Type t` do some processing and will store the results into an `std::string` by reference.

```
template<class Type>
struct Test {
    Test( Type t, std::string& str ) {
        static_assert( std::is_arithmetic<Type>::value, "Arithmetic type required." );
        if ( std::is_arithmetic<Type>::value ) { // check if type is arithmetic
            // some variables here

            // Note: I do not want to static_assert here if type is integral. 
            // If assert fails the else will not be executed.
            if ( std::is_integral<type>::value ) {

                // some code for integral types
            } else {

                // some other code for arithmetic non integral types (floating point types)
            }
            str = // some code.

        } else {
            // possibly throw some exception
        }
    }
};
```

Is this an adequate way to resolve branch decisions based on `data type`? Or is there a more desirable-efficient way of doing this?

- I could have a default constructor with a few member variables and overload 2 or 3 functions
- I could do partial specialization of the class (not preferred).
- I could just eliminate the "class-struct" altogether and do this as a function template, however, I would prefer to instantiate objects of this type.

Comment: Change `if` to C++17's [`if constexpr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if).

Comment: @O'Neil I have limited support for C++17

Comment: @O'Neil ok, to my surprise; visual studio 2017 CE was set to default C++14 when the field in the project settings is left blank. There is a flag to set it to C++17 or C++latest. I had to do some research to find that out. So I do have support for the `if constexpr( ... ) { }` after all. I do know though that MS Visual Studio is limited on some of the `C++17` features as opposed to `clang or gcc`. Nice little safe guard! :)

Answer (score 1):

What about mixing tag dispatching and delegating constructors?

I mean... something like

```
template <typename Type>
struct Test
 {
   Test (Type t, std::string & str, std::true_type const &,
         std::true_type const &)
    { str = "case arithmetic and integral"; }

   Test (Type t, std::string & str, std::true_type const &,
         std::false_type const &)
    { str = "case arithmetic but not integral"; }

   Test (Type t, std::string & str, std::false_type const &, ...)
    { str = "case not arithmetic"; /* + throw ? */ }

   Test (Type t, std::string & str)
      : Test(t, str, std::is_arithmetic<Type>{}, std::is_integral<Type>{})
    { }
};


int main ()
 { 
   std::string  str;

   Test<int>(0, str);

   std::cout << str << std::endl;

   Test<float>(0.0f, str);

   std::cout << str << std::endl;

   Test<std::string>("zero", str);

   std::cout << str << std::endl;
 }
```

If the common code is relevant, you can define a single delegating constructor for the arithmetic types and use tag dispatching with a member called in the body.

That is

```
template <typename Type>
struct Test
 {
   void func (std::string & str, std::true_type const &)
    { str = "case integral"; }

   void func (std::string & str, std::false_type const &)
    { str = "case not integral"; }

   Test (Type t, std::string & str, std::true_type const &)
    {
      // variable definition and common code

      func(str, /* other variables */ std::is_integral<Type>{});

      // other common code 
      str += " plus common";
    }

   Test (Type t, std::string & str, std::false_type const &)
    { str = "case not arithmetic"; /* + throw ? */ }

   Test (Type t, std::string & str)
      : Test(t, str, std::is_arithmetic<Type>{})
    { }
};
```

Comment: After doing some research; I found out that in MS Visual Studio 2017 in the project settings there is a blank field that set's the default compiler to `(/std:c++14)`. This flag can be set to `(/std:c++17)` or  `(/std:c++latest)`. So I do have support for `c++17` after all. I do like your answer; but I think I'm going to go with `O'neil's` comment to my question by adding in the `constexpr` within the if statement. It makes life a whole lot easier... although your solution with `tag dispatching` does make it easier for the reader-user to understand the constructors better.

Comment: @FrancisCugler - I'm agree: if you can use C++17, `if constexpr` is the best choice.